# SecurityManager surprises

Tags: java, securitymanager

I wanted to create a very restrictive security manager, so I extended SecurityManager and overridden all the custom checkXXX methods.

But then I found out that my security manager is useless, because anyone can just:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

So I have to add:

```
@Override    public void checkPermission(Permission perm)  {
    if (perm.getName().equals("setSecurityManager")) {
        throw new SecurityException("You shall have no other security manager but me!");
    }
}
```

Are there any more surprises? Any other things I have to do to make my SecurityManager hermetic?

Comment: I don't know why this this is a surprise. It's specified in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least a couple of things I can think of:

1. Someone could use reflection to set the `System.security` field to accessible, and then set it to whatever they want.
2. Someone could use [sun.misc.Unsafe](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/712) to directly overwrite your instance in memory with whatever random thing they want.

I think your `SecurityManager` can guard against these things, since they both rely on calls to `Field.setAccessible()`.  But better to test it out to make sure.

Comment: 1. I tried this: systemSecurityField = java.lang.Class.forName("java.lang.System").getDeclaredField("security"); but got java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: security

Comment: Strange, it works for me (using Java 6, update 24).  Using:  `System.class.getDeclaredField("security");`